# AJAX + autocomplete

Tags: ajax, jsp, autocomplete

I have a JSP page with a vector object which has about 10000 words.

Currently I am displaying them in a table format. Now I want to introduce a text box, where I enter the work and autocomplete is a part of it and the table below also gets updated with the results of the auto complete list.

Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out this functionality using jQuery table (http://www.datatables.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).

Comment: That didn't help, may be I need to give more information. I have a vector object and using struts 1.2, so its in my JSP. A text box will take an input and I need to show the autocomplete and the results to be displayed in a table below, so both the autocomplete and table are update simultaneously.